# SQL Server Management Studio - UNPIVOT Query for n columns, n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to unpivot a dataset which looks like this:

[image]

To this:

```
+-------------+-----------------+---------+
| Scenario ID | Distribution ID |  Value  |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+
|           0 | Number1         |      10 |
|           0 | Number2         |      19 |
|           0 | Number3         |    34.3 |
|           0 | Number4         |   60.31 |
|           0 | Number5         | 104.527 |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+
```

Using SQL System Management Studio.

I think I should use a code which is based on something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_name
) AS cp 
UNPIVOT 
(
  Scenario FOR Scenarios IN (*
) AS up;
```

Can anyone help me with this? I do not know how to code, just starting.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The structure is perfect after I applied the advice I got below, however the values seems not correct, it is capturing only firs 2 digits (the Values are in billions plus 2 decimals)...

Comment: I appreciate your understanding with that other question. As you can see, this one include what you tried, and is a bit more specific, and nice to see how it worked out for you! And welcome to the next level of privileges, such as upvoting or flagging things ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t.scenarioid, tt.distributionId, tt.value
from table t cross apply
     ( values (Number1, 'Number1'), (Number2, 'Number2'), . . .   
     ) tt (value, distributionId);
```

Yes, you need to list out all possible `Numbers` first time only.

Comment: Thank you!! It looks like it worked!! I just need to save it now in a database. I need to list all (Number1, 'Number1') ... all the time?

Comment: hey, the query works and I found out how to put those results into a new table, but the values are not full (my values are in billions, after unpivoting I get only integers) I dont know how to find out why. I tried to declare a variable type: create table test2 ([ScenarioID] int, [Distribution] varchar(50), 
                           [Value] decimal(20,3)) 
insert into test2 
Select t.[Concatenated ID], tt.[Distribution], tt.[Value]
From test1 t cross apply
 (values (1-6-0-00-00, '1-6-0-00-00'), ... But the values are still not correct..

Comment: I dont know how to Google the t letter added in your example: t.scenarioid or tt.distributionId. I do not know how to call it to search for it? If you recommend any website/video on this I would appreciete!

Comment: @user10484829. . . `t` is your table alias nothing else,  it could be different.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need a dynamic `unpivot` solution (that can handle any number of columns) try this:

```
create table [dbo].[Test] ([ScenarioID] int,        [Number1] decimal(10,3), 
                           [Number2] decimal(10,3), [Number3] decimal(10,3),
                           [Number4] decimal(10,3), [Number5] decimal(10,3)) 

insert into [dbo].[Test] select 0, 10, 19, 34.3, 60.31, 104.527

declare @sql  nvarchar(max) = '' 
declare @cols nvarchar(max) = '' 

select @cols = @cols +','+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' and TABLE_NAME='test' and COLUMN_NAME like 'Number%' 
order by ORDINAL_POSITION 

set @cols = substring(@cols, 2, LEN(@cols)) 

set @sql = @sql + ' select u.[ScenarioID], u.[DistributionID], u.[Value]  
                     from [dbo].[Test] s  
                     unpivot  
                     (  
                     [Value]   
                     for [DistributionID] in ('+ @cols + ')  
                     ) u;' 

execute(@sql)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `VALUES`:

```
SELECT T.scenarioId, s.*
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Number1', t.Number1),
                    ('Number2', t.Number2)) AS s(DistId, Val)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `cross apply` for this:

```
select t.scenarioid, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('Number1', number1), ('Number2', number2), . . . 
     ) v(distributionId, number);
```

You need to list out all the numbers.

Why do I prefer `cross apply` over `unpivot`?  I find the `unpivot` syntax to be *very* specific.  It pretty much does exactly one thing.  On the other hand, `apply` introduces lateral joins.  These are very powerful, and `apply` can be used in many different situations.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!! :) Thanks Ill read about those possibilities more!